# JPA query, select articles with two or more approved reviews

Tags: sql, jpa

Each article has three reviews; review has "approved" column (true means the review accepts the article, false means deny). How to select articles which has two or more approved reviews?

```
mysql> describe article;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| content      | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| author_id    | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> describe review;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| comment     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| approved    | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| article_id  | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| reviewer_id | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

HERE I want to use a query in JPA Reporsitory:

```
public interface ArticleRepository extends JpaRepository<Article, Integer>{

    @Query("XXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
    public List<Article> findApprovedArticles();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a correlated subquery:

```
"select a from Article a where
    (select count(*) from Review r where r.articleId = a.id and r.approved = 1) >= 2"
```